# ¿Como hago para editar un registro ya existe en la base de datos en Django y que no me agregue otro?

Tags: python, django

Hola¡ Llevo tiempo intentanto editar mi resgistros en django pero en vez de eso me agrega uno nuevo, por favor alguien que me ayude.

Esta es mi función para editar:

```
def editarempleado (request, id_empleado):
    p = Empleados.objects.get(pk=id_empleado)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EmpleadoForm(request.POST,instance=p)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect ('empleados')
    else:
        form = EmpleadoForm(instance=p) 

    ctx = {'formulario' : form}

    return render_to_response("empleados/editar.html", ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Este es mi url :

```
url(r'^editar/(?P<id_empleado>\d+)$', SGregorio_views.editarempleado, name='editar'),
```

Esta es mi plantilla:

```
{% load staticfiles%}

<head>
    <title>San Gregorio</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{% static "css/estilos.css" %}'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{% static "css/font-awesome.min.css" %}'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='{% static "js/bootstrap.min.js" %}'></script>
    <script src='{% static "js/estilos.js" %}'></script>
</head>
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="cerrarmodal">
        <a href="{% url 'empleados' %}"> <i class="fa fa-close"> </i></a>
    </button>
    <h4> <span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>Actualizar empleado</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form class="formatolinea" method="post" name="Formulario">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label>Codigo</label>
            <input type="number" value="{{id_empleado}}">
            <label>Nombre</label>
            {{formulario.nombre}}
            <label>Apellidos</label>
            {{formulario.apellidos}}
            <label>tipo de documento</label>
            {{formulario.tipo_documento}}
            <label>Número de documento</label>
            {{formulario.numero_documento}}
            <label>Fecha de nacimiento</label>
            {{formulario.fecha_nacimiento}}
            <label>Edad</label>
            {{formulario.edad}}
            <label>Sexo</label>
            {{formulario.sexo}}
            <label>dirección</label>
            {{formulario.direccion}}
            <label>teléfono</label>
            {{formulario.telefono}}
            <label>correo electrónico</label>
            {{formulario.email}}
            <label>Fecha de ingreso</label>
            {{formulario.fecha_ingreso}}
            <label>Tiempo laborando</label>
            {{formulario.tiempo_laborando}}
            <label>Tipo de contrato </label>
            {{formulario.tipo_contrato}}
            <label>Salario</label>
            {{formulario.salario}}
            <label>EPS</label>
            {{formulario.eps}}
            <label>AFP</label>
            {{formulario.afp}}
            <label>Cesantias</label>
            {{formulario.cesantias}}
            <label>Seguro Exequial</label>
            {{formulario.seguro_exequial}}
            <label>Crediflores</label>
            {{formulario.cesantias}}
            <label>Cargo</label>
            {{formulario.cargo}}
            <label>Cuenta banco</label>
            {{formulario.cuenta}}
            <button class="guardar" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Guardar</button>
            <button class="cancelar" type="reset"> <a href="{% url 'empleados' %}"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Cancelar </a></button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Alguien que me ayude por favor.

Comment: Pega tu urls.py, a lo mejor ahí está el problema.

Comment: Ahora puedes pegar la plantilla `empleados/editar.html`. No se ve ningún problema en el código que publicaste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def editarempleado (request, id_empleado):
  p = Empleados.objects.get(pk=id_empleado) #aqui tienen tu objeto de tipo Empleado
  if request.method == "POST":
     form = EmpleadoForm(request.POST,instance=p)
     if form.is_valid():
         form.save() #aqui estas guardando diractamente el formulario en la base de datos
         return redirect ('empleados')
 else:
    form = EmpleadoForm(instance=p) 

 ctx = {'formulario' : form}

 return render_to_response("empleados/editar.html", ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

para acutalizar un registro tienes que acceder al atributo de tu objeto y modificarlo luego guardarlo

```
def editarempleado (request, id_empleado):
  p = Empleados.objects.get(pk=id_empleado)
  if request.method == "POST":
     form = EmpleadoForm(request.POST,instance=p)
     if form.is_valid():
        p.nombre_empleado = request.POST['nuevo_nombre'] #nose que quieres editar solo es un ejemplo
        p.apellido_empleado = request.POST['nuevo_apellid'] #solo es un ejemplo
        p.save()
        return redirect ('empleados')
     else : 
        form = EmpleadoForm(instance=p)
        ctx = {'formulario' : form}
        return render_to_response("empleados/editar.html", ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request)) #esto lo pongo porque si el formulario no es valido tiene que devolver el error (estoy repitiendo mucho codigo arreglalo)
 else:
    form = EmpleadoForm(instance=p) 

 ctx = {'formulario' : form}

 return render_to_response("empleados/editar.html", ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Y si quiero editar varios campos a la vez como lo puedo hacer?

Comment: cuando tienes el objeto puedes acceder a todos sus atributos

Comment: tu modelo Empleado tiene atributos cuando envías el formulario a la plantilla tienes que enviarlo con los campos que quieres que se editen y luego en la vista accedes a los campos del formulario y se los asignas a los campos de tu objeto empleado.

Comment: Se sigue creando un nuevo registro es vez de editarlo, ya no se que más hacer alguien por favor que me ayude.